# What am I suppose to do for the following emergency instruction

Tags: meaning

Can anyone tell me what exactly am I suppose to do for the following first emergency instruction saying

> Enlist the aid of the nearest person (when available) to direct emergency personnel to the location of emergency.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not just direct the emergency personnel to the location of injured person? It does not seem right to move to injured person from one location to other.

Comment: According to your context, they are not talking about injured people; They are talking about asking an uninjured, unaffected person (if available) to direct emergency personnel to the scene. Presumably this is the course of action for on-location persons to take command and direct, until the official response has arrived.

Comment: It means **Look around for someone nearby—close enough that you can talk to them without leaving the injured person. Check that they can help you (not also injured, you can understand each other, etc.). If they can help, tell them to watch for police/ambulance/firefighters and bring them to you as quickly as possible.**

Comment: It means grab someone (whoever is nearby) and have them tell the firefighters/EMTs/Police to the emergency.  But this is not a question for this site.  When you visit a new internet community, you might want to take a minute to learn the correct etiquette for that community so as not to irritate people.  In this case, you might want to [take the tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on [what you can ask](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask it](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for all  the answers and critiques. I got the meaning now.

Comment: @Cascabel There is an answer and it's been accepted. It works that way these days.

Comment: @Kris sorry...not sure if I catch your drift. The question is unclear and shows little research. It will probably close for those reasons.  That is the way it is _supposed_ to work these days.

Comment: @Cascabel Right. But see what's happening.

Comment: The question is not about the English language and usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enlist, as a transitive verb, is defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enlist) as "to secure the support and aid of." In an emergency, this could be done either by calling the attention of or physically assisting the nearest person and directing them to go to the agreed emergency or evacuation point.